# Tomcat requests load issue "Connection refused"

Tags: tomcat

I have an app on tomcat 7.50, works fine on single request but on many simultanious requests (~1200) I'm getting:

```
2014-11-02 11:22:48,485 ERROR  [MONITOR-AGENT ] Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused from url http://localhost:9080/monitorLog/monitor?id=21812&name=sv17222_DB82C_201410282357.log...
2014-11-02 11:22:48,485 ERROR  [MONITOR-AGENT ] Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused 

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9080 refused

        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)

        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)

        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:941)

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:919)

        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:910)

        at com.securegion.monitoragent.monitor.MonitorAgent.httpGet(MonitorAgent.java:291)

        at com.securegion.monitoragent.monitor.MonitorAgent.monitor(MonitorAgent.java:239)

        at com.securegion.monitoragent.monitor.MonitorAgent.check(MonitorAgent.java:203)

        at com.securegion.monitoragent.engine.Agent.run(Agent.java:35)

        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)

        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)

        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)

        ... 14 more
```

My server.xml connector:

```
<Connector port="9080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="60000"
redirectPort="8443" keepAliveTimeout = "-1"
maxThreads="150" acceptCount="1500"/>
```

It's fine if some requests will be rejected and will be resolved in next iteration, but just few (~5) are getting a success before server giving me those messaggs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was actually memory issue. after releasing some stack memory by deleting the -Xmx attribute, issue was solved